# CSS property filter: contrast(0%) doesn't work on Firefox(v. 35.0.1)

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I tried to achieve a contrast effect on the logos for this page --> http://momarredi.homenet.org/

I used

img {filter: contrast(0%);}

to apply the effect on every image of the site. Everything is working fine in chrome and safari and opera, but not in firefox (I am on version 35.0.1).

I put now some code trying to simulate the effect, but with poor results..

Do you have any advice?

Thank you all

Comment: I think contrast wants an absolute value, not a percentage, try: img {filter: contrast(0);}

Comment: note: Css filters are heavy to render, you might want to consider applying filters in photoshop and using normal images

Comment: Thank you @JonasGrumann, it was so simple! I need to use this css effect because it is a wordpress custom loop, so it need to function even with new posts... (there is an hover effect to get rid of the filter)..

Thank you again

Comment: Well in that case consider doing it server side

Comment: Hoe can I do that? can you link me some resources that I can read to undestrand in wich direction  I have to go?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you using any kind of back end? Is it a wordpress site? Joomla? Others? Or is it just a static html/css/js site?

Comment: It's made with wordpress, a mix of custom tempalte and pages modified from an existing one